# Как сделать запрет на закрытие формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать запрет на закрытие пользовательской формы?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно подписаться на событие `FormClosing` и, используя аргумент `FormClosingEventArgs`, отменять закрытие формы.

```
private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   //Отменяем закрытие формы
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно скрыть кнопку закрытия формы:

```
private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
        myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON ;
        return myCp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это ведь можно в дизайнере сделать, нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy, насколько я помню, в дизайнере можно задизейблить только кнопки "Свернуть" и "Развернуть".

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте в обработчик событий формы `Close` сделать проверку и запрещать(или розрешать) закрытие при помощи `e.Close = false` или `e.Close = true`

Comment: Вроде соседний ответ правильнее. А тут и событие не то, и свойство - тоже.